# 32 BIT PC for Development/Programming?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop-computer, web-development

I am .NET(ASP.NET) and Java developer since 2005. I mainly used 64 bit machines(Windows). But in my new company they gave me 32 bit machine(x86 CPU). I need to run visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2015, NetBeans, Sql Server and other development IDE. Will these software's works fine in my new PC?

Comment: It is the responsibility of your employer to ensure that the tools they give you work together. If they do, you will know the answer. If they don't, talk to your employer, not to strangers on the Internet.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, my question is that will these IDEs works or not?

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume that they don't? I mean, it's not like 32 bit computers are some form of obscure technology with no support from Microsoft.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 and earlier are actually 32-bit *only*. http://www.quora.com/Why-is-Visual-Studio-2015-still-a-32-bit-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be memory: when you run Visual Studio, SSMS and Firefox and couple of other apps, you will easily reach 4 GB physical memory limit. So better use SSD disk. It will work but available memory is an important performance factor on a development machine.